# Out of memory error on initializing Couchbase java Client

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-java-api, couchbase-java-client

Facing out of memory error on initializing Couchbase Java Client. The issue happens in the context of running Test cases in the Gradle build. It doesn't seem to be happening when running individual test cases. It seems to be happening on running all test cases in the build.  The error is occurring on MacOS and not on  Linux build machine

Environment

```
JVM = 16 (OpenJDK)
OS = MacOS Monterey
task = Gradle build 
jvm memory settings = -Xmx8000m" "-Xms512m" "-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=2000m"
```

StackTrace -

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Cannot reserve 16384 bytes of direct buffer memory (allocated: 536861104, limit: 536870912)
    at java.base/java.nio.Bits.reserveMemory(Bits.java:178)
    at java.base/java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.<init>(DirectByteBuffer.java:121)
    at java.base/java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(ByteBuffer.java:330)
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.unix.Buffer.allocateDirectWithNativeOrder(Buffer.java:40)
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.unix.IovArray.<init>(IovArray.java:72)
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.kqueue.KQueueEventLoop.<init>(KQueueEventLoop.java:62)
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.kqueue.KQueueEventLoopGroup.newChild(KQueueEventLoopGroup.java:151)
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.kqueue.KQueueEventLoopGroup.newChild(KQueueEventLoopGroup.java:32)
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:84)
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:60)
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:49)
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.MultithreadEventLoopGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventLoopGroup.java:59)
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.kqueue.KQueueEventLoopGroup.<init>(KQueueEventLoopGroup.java:110)
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.kqueue.KQueueEventLoopGroup.<init>(KQueueEventLoopGroup.java:97)
    at com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.kqueue.KQueueEventLoopGroup.<init>(KQueueEventLoopGroup.java:73)
    at com.couchbase.client.core.env.IoEnvironment.createEventLoopGroup(IoEnvironment.java:476)
    at com.couchbase.client.core.env.IoEnvironment.<init>(IoEnvironment.java:285)
    at com.couchbase.client.core.env.IoEnvironment.<init>(IoEnvironment.java:66)
    at com.couchbase.client.core.env.IoEnvironment$Builder.build(IoEnvironment.java:674)
    at com.couchbase.client.core.env.CoreEnvironment.<init>(CoreEnvironment.java:153)
    at com.couchbase.client.java.env.ClusterEnvironment.<init>(ClusterEnvironment.java:53)
    at com.couchbase.client.java.env.ClusterEnvironment.<init>(ClusterEnvironment.java:46)
    at com.couchbase.client.java.env.ClusterEnvironment$Builder.build(ClusterEnvironment.java:213)
```

Comment: Would you please update with which version of Couchbase you're using and which version of the Couchbase Java SDK you're using?